# Is 'bool' a basic datatype in C++?

Tags: c++

I got this doubt while writing some code. Is 'bool' a basic datatype defined in the C++ standard or is it some sort of extension provided by the compiler ? I got this doubt because Win32 has 'BOOL' which is nothing but a typedef of long. Also what happens if I do something like this:

```
int i = true;
```

Is it "always" guaranteed that variable i will have value 1 or is it again depends on the compiler I am using ? Further for some Win32 APIs which accept BOOL as the parameter what happens if I pass bool variable?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

bool is a fundamental datatype in C++. Converting `true` to an integer type will yield 1, and converting `false` will yield 0 (4.5/4 and 4.7/4). In C, until C99, there was no bool datatype, and people did stuff like

```
enum bool {
    false, true
};
```

So did the Windows API. Starting with C99, we have `_Bool` as a basic data type. Including `stdbool.h` will <strike>typedef</strike> `#define` that to `bool` and provide the constants `true` and `false`. They didn't make bool a basic data-type (and thus a keyword) because of compatibility issues with existing code.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, bool is a built-in type.

WIN32 is C code, not C++, and C does not have a bool, so they provide their own typedef BOOL.

Comment: C does have a bool now, but it didn't way back when the win32 api first came into existence.

Comment: There's also BOOLEAN and VARIANT_BOOL: see http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/12/22/329884.aspx

Comment: Joel: Ok, Win32 is C89 then, which doesn't have a bool. ;)

Answer (score 5):

C++ does lots of automatic casting for you - that is, if you have a variable of type `bool` and pass it to something expecting an `int`, it will make it into an `int` for you - `0` for `false` and `1` for `true`.

I don't have my standard around to see if this is guaranteed, but every compiler I've used does this (so one can assume it will always work).

However, relying on this conversion is a bad idea. Code can stop compiling if a new method is added that overloads the `int` signature, etc.

Answer (score 2):

yes, it was introduced in 1993.

for further reference: [Boolean Datatype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_datatype#C.2B.2B)

Comment: Sorry, I don't see from the _Boolean Datatype_ page where `bool` became part of the C language in 1993.  Now in 1999, the C99 standard added a boolean built-in type: it is called `_Bool`.  (It is `typedef`ed to `bool` for convenience but `bool` is not actually a built-in type itself.)

Comment: @ColinDBennett, Yes, there is no citation at that link. However, the question was about C++, so C is tangential. Quick Googling doesn't find any categorical citations for C++ and 1993, only a _proposal_ to add `bool` written in that year. I don't feel like belabouring the search and assume the real answer is buried in some standard somewhere. Either way, this effectively link-only answer is now orphaned.

Comment: OK, you are right, I somehow missed the fact that question was about C++.  At least [the Cppreference history of C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/history) states that `bool` was added in the ISO C++98 version of the language.

Answer (score 2):

C is meant to be a step above assembly language. The C if-statement is really just syntactical sugar for "branch-if-zero", so the idea of booleans as an independent datatype was a foreign concept at the time. (1)

Even now, C/C++ booleans are usually little more than an alias for a single byte data type. As such, it's really more of a purposing label than an independent datatype.

(1) Of course, modern compilers are a bit more advanced in their handling of if statements. This is from the standpoint of C as a new language.

Answer (score 2):

Turbo c and c++ compiler does not support boolean (bool keyword) data type but dev c++ compiler supports boolean  (bool keyword) data type.

Comment: Turbo c/c++ isn't C99 compliant - it uses a very old (and now obsolete) standard, so you cant see the bool keyword over there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, C++ supports bool and it is a data type.
For reference - [Bool data type](https://www.studytonight.com/cpp/datatypes-and-modifiers-in-cpp.php)

Comment: Unfortunately, your answer does not really add anything other answers did not already state. Also you ignored the second part of the question.

Answer (score -1):

Allthough it's now a native type, it's still defined behind the scenes as an integer (int I think) where the literal `false` is 0 and `true` is 1. But I think all logic still consider anything but 0 as true, so strictly speaking the true literal is probably a keyword for the compiler to test if something is not false.

```
if(someval == true){
```

probably translates to:

```
if(someval !== false){ // e.g. someval !== 0
```

by the compiler

Comment: It might be possible to implement it that way, but, at least in the case of VC++, the 4 bytes underlying a bool value are always set to 0 or 1.

Comment: By which I mean, the four bytes *interpreted as an int* have the value 0 or 1

Comment: You are thinking of a language like VB perhaps, this is not correct for C++. x == true is not a shorthand for some kind of test for truthiness of x, it is an application of the '==' operator to two values.  Of course, the mind-boggling rules of C++ apply, to select which overloaded operator== applies, and to coerce the values of x and true...