# C++ bool returns 0 1 instead of true false

Tags: c++, overloading, boolean

I have overloaded equals (including == and !=) that checks if two objects are equals and then returns a boolean.

Unfortunately, it prints 0 or 1. I know it's correct but I can't figure out the way to make it to print true or false for readability purposes.

I've even tried:

```
if (a.equals(b))
{
    return true;
}

return false;
```

However, C++ is stubborn enough to output 0 or 1.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit - Print is done:

```
cout << "a == b is " << (a == b) << endl;
```

Desired output is

> a == b is true

Comment: someone correct me if i'm wrong but isn't boolean just an uint enum?

Comment: @dubvfan no, `sizeof(bool) == 1` on my platform so not `uint`. But they're really just 1 and 0 underneath.

Comment: You mention printing but your code does not include anything that would output. Please show us the complete code. I suspect you're bool is getting cast to an int during output.

Comment: @dubvfan87 C++ has a fundamental boolean type, whose size is not specified by the standard...and though it might appear to behave like an `int`, it isn't one...you can assign 35 to a bool and still it will test for equality with `== true`.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356726/is-bool-a-basic-datatype-in-c

Comment: @HostileFork but what about 34? Or 1 << 9 (You see the difference)

Comment: @SethCarnegie I do not see the difference.  You can assign any value to a bool and if it converts to "truth" then you can test that bool against `true` and it will work.  However, it will not test as equal to what you assigned to it.  This is different from the kinds of tricks used to implement bools from the C days.  The following code prints only "b == true": `bool b = 34; if (b == 34) { cout << "b == 34" << endl; } if (b == true) { cout << "b == true" << endl; }`

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can use [`std::boolalpha`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha):

> Sets the boolalpha format flag for the str stream.
>
> When the boolalpha format flag is set, bool values are
>   inserted/extracted as their names: true and false instead of integral
>   values.
>
> This flag can be unset with the noboolalpha manipulator.
>
> The boolalpha flag is not set in standard streams on initialization.

```
std::cout.setf(std::ios::boolalpha);
std::cout << true;
```

or

```
std::cout << std::boolalpha << true;
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to use `std::boolalpha`:

```
cout << boolalpha << yourthing() << endl;
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to use `std::boolalpha` to print true/false :

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << true << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This fixes it directly

```
std::cout << std::boolalpha << "a == b is " << (a == b) << '\n';
```

With this it covers it general without repeating std::boolalpha

```
std::cout.setf(std::ios::boolalpha);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this outside of a stream output `<<`, it's a simple ternary expression:

```
std::string str = (a == b) ? "true" : "false";
```