# printing the value of bool data type in c++

Tags: c++

I am learning C++, I came across a question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356726/is-bool-a-basic-datatype-in-c) which says bool is a fundamental data type in C++, However when I printed the value of true or false I got result as 1 or 0. I expected true or false.

I decided to overload << operator for printing `true` string for boolean true value and `false` string for false value, but when I overloaded the function I am getting an error `error: ambiguous overload for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::basic_ostream<char>' and 'bool')`

I believe this is because << is already overloaded to print 1 for true and 0 for false. Isn't it wrong to print 1 for true and 0 for false when bool is a fundamental data type?

Just to clarify for down voters, It is not that I can't make it work, I wanted to ask why it is designed to work this way. If you see popular language such as python this is not the case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8261674/c-bool-returns-0-1-instead-of-true-false

Comment: Keep in mind true and false are English and wouldn't be suitable for user consumption in another language. I wouldn't be surprised if that factors into not making it the default.

Comment: @chris Although the other behavior when the `boolalpha` flag is set on the `ostream` does depend on the stream's locale.

Comment: @aschepler, That's why I put default. Going through the locale is slower (although I can't defend that considering this is IOstreams) and being the default could lead to people assuming the output will always be the same, then running into problems for locale changes later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
bool b1 = false;
bool b2 = true;

std::cout << std::boolalpha << b1 << std::endl;
std::cout << std::noboolalpha << b1 << std::endl;

std::cout << std::boolalpha << b2 << std::endl;
std::cout << std::noboolalpha << b2 << std::endl;
```

Output :

```
false
0

true
1
```