# Can we assign the result of a logical expression to an integer variable?

Tags: c++, integer, boolean

I searched about this issue but the answer I found was that the result of a logical expression cannot be assigned to an integer variable it can be only assigned to a boolean variable, but then I tried a simple code to check my point that the result can be assigned to an integer variable because in the first place the logical expression returns an integer value.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n1 = 1;
    int n2 = 2;
    int b;
    b = (n1 == n2);
    cout<<b;
}
```

Basically is this case the result of the logical expression is false which means it's 0
[image]

> So why is it wrong to store the result in an integer value??

[Here's one of the websites](https://www.dummies.com/programming/cpp/store-logical-values-in-c/)
[Here's another one](https://quizlet.com/244347756/c-chapter-4-flash-cards/#:%7E:text=False-,The%20result%20of%20a%20logical%20expression%20cannot%20be%20assigned%20to,assigned%20to%20a%20bool%20variable.&text=In%20C%2B%2B%2C%20both%20!%20and,are%20relational%20operators.)

Comment: If you want to see "true" and "false" printed in `std::cout`, use [`boolalph`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha) (ie: at the beginning of `main()`, run `std::cout << std::boolalpha;`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ bool returns 0 1 instead of true false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8261674/c-bool-returns-0-1-instead-of-true-false)

Comment: "because in the first place the logical expression returns an integer value" No. In C++ logical expression returns `bool` (in C it was true). But `bool` is implicitly convertible to integer values.

Comment: Please provide a link to the "answer" you found on the internet that claims "_the result of a logical expression cannot be assigned to an integer variable_". Otherwise it is difficult to guess why such a claim has been made. Maybe it was just a statement in a quiz, with the correct answer being that statement is actually false. Or maybe it was not about C++.

Comment: @heap underrun check it now

Comment: To quote the first website you linked: "_The result of a logical operation in C++ can be assigned to a variable of type bool._". However, they do not claim it cannot be assigned to a variable of type `int` instead, if you want. On the second website you linked, there is a quiz, and the (second) question of that quiz is whether the statement "_The result of a logical expression cannot be assigned to an int variable, but it can be assigned to a bool variable._" is true or false. The correct answer is false (scroll down to see all the correct answers, or just flip the card with the statement).

Comment: @heap underrun, now it's clear thank you so much for your time and effort.

Comment: You claim (in question, and in comment to the answer you have acepted) that web sites keep saying it is wrong to store the result (of a logical expression) in an integer variable.   Neither site you link to says any such thing.  If you are drawing that conclusion, then you are misinterpreting what those web  sites say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you say:

```
b = (n1 == n2);
```

the compiler says:

```
b = int(n1 == n2);
```

this concept is known as **implicit type conversion.**

Comment: @N . Prone I know the boolean result will be implicitly conserved to integer when we store it in an integer variable so this is valid in c++  but why whenever I search it's said that we can't store the result in an integer but we actually can because it will be conserved implicitly to an integer.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion "the type bool can be converted to int with the value false becoming ​0​ and true becoming 1."