# Initialization of boolean variables

Tags: c++, boolean

This question might seem naive (hell, I think it is) but I am unable to find an answer that satisfies me.

Take this simple C++ program:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    bool b;
    cout << b;
    return 0;
}
```

When compiled and executed, it *always* prints `0`.

The problem is that is not what I'm expecting it to do: as far as I know, a local variable has no initialization value, and I believe that a random byte has more chances of being different rather than equal to `0`.

What am I missing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356726/is-bool-a-basic-datatype-in-c

Comment: You aren't missing anything. It could be `true` or `false`, and you cannot rely on it being always `false`.

Comment: You should look at the output assembly code. I think the place where the bool resides is reused from a variable that was previously assigned a 0.

Comment: When memory is allocated by the operating system to a program it usually clears it to zero bytes to prevent the program from reading whatever might have been in that memory before. So your program just picks that up. It's not random as such, but there is nothing in the language that defines what the value will be. It might always be false on your platform. Other platforms or compilers might always be true. Or might base it on the day of the week :) Nothing in the c++ standard requires it to have any defined value, but your platform might always set it to one.

Comment: The value is "random" in the sense that you can't predict it. That's obviously true, since your prediction isn't correct. `<g>`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is undefined behavior, because you are using the value of an uninitialized variable. You cannot expect anything out of a program with undefined behavior.

In particular, your program necessitates a so-called *lvalue-to-rvalue* conversion when initializing the parameter of `operator <<` from `b`. Paragraph 4.1/1 of the C++11 Standard specifies:

> A glvalue (3.10) of a non-function, non-array type `T` can be converted to a prvalue. If `T` is an incomplete
>   type, a program that necessitates this conversion is ill-formed. If the object to which the glvalue refers is not
>   an object of type `T` and is not an object of a type derived from `T`, **or if the object is uninitialized, a program
>   that necessitates this conversion has undefined behavior**. If `T` is a non-class type, the type of the prvalue is
>   the `cv`-unqualified version of `T`. Otherwise, the type of the prvalue is `T`.

Comment: I know that, but I don't understand why I keep on getting `0` as output; am I *that* lucky? :)

Comment: @Cynical: Well, the right answer should be "*I don't know, I don't care*". it's undefined behavior, so you may well be *that* lucky. Or your compiler may decide to initialize uninitialized variables to `0` in debug builds and format your hard drive in release builds

Comment: @Cynical no point in trying to understand why some code that is UB does something in certain situations.

Comment: Undefined behavior != random behavior.  Undefined behavior is very often non-random on the same system.

Comment: Thanks both and @Mike, now the thing is clear; I'll mark this answer as the accepted one (in 7 minutes) just because it was the first one.

Comment: @kgraney: I did not write anything that contradicts what you wrote ;)

Comment: @Cynical The undefined behaviour may be repeatable. It's an implementation detail, and could change. Try compiling in release, debug, with different optimisations, etc, you might get different, repeatable results. Then again, you might not.

Comment: @Andy: Oh I know, just trying to clarify a bit.

Answer (score 6):

The behaviour is undefined; there is no requirement for it to be assigned a random value, and certainly not a uniformly-distributed one.

What is probably happening is that the memory allocated to the process is zero-initialised by the operating system, and this is the first time that that byte is used, so it still contains zero.

But, like all undefined behaviour, you can't rely on it and there's little point speculating about the details.

Answer (score 1):

As Andy said, it's undefined behaviour. I think the fact that you are so lucky and always receive 0 is implementation defined. Probably the stack is empty and clean (initialized with zeros) when you program starts. So it happens that you get zero when allocation a variable there.

Answer (score 0):

This may be guaranteed to succeed in your current implementation (as others said, maybe it initializes the stack with zeros) but it's also guaranteed to fail in, say, a Visual C++ debug build (which initializes local variables to 0xCCCCCCCC).

Answer (score 0):

C++ static and global variables are initialized by default as C89 and C99 says - and specifically arithmetic variables are initialized by 0.

Auto variables are `indeterminate` which by C89 and C99 at `3.17.2` means that they are either an unspecified value or a trap representation. Trap representation in the context of bool type might mean 0 - this is compiler specific.